# Calling countifs in vba with <>

Tags: vba, excel

does anyone know why the following line errors?

```
answer = WorksheetFunction.counitfs(myrange, "<>x", myrange, "<>y")
```

I am trying to find the number of values in a range that are not equal to x or y. It works in Excel, but not in vba, not too sure why...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more code first ? So we can at leat see the variable declaration and can you tell us what error is displayed exactly ?

Comment: _'It doesn't work'_ is not a problem description. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled your code, it should read as:

```
answer = WorksheetFunction.countifs(myrange, "<>x", myrange, "<>y")
```

Comment: I'm a moron. Thank you!